# Modifying CSV Files with pandas?

Tags: pandas

I was playing with pandas for the first time and I see huge potential in cleaning up some of our CSV files (data types, column names, add some additional columns based on other values in the file, etc).

I was thinking of only selecting certain columns based on their column name in the .csv file. Like for a file with 50 columns I might just select some critical ones like this:

```
usecols = ['Person ID', 'Interaction Date', 'Case ID', 'Overall Score',
           'Interaction Reason', 'Center Location']
```

Some of these values are also on separate files so it seems like a good idea to create new titles for them and ensure that the data type is correct. I was going to use the inplace command.

```
df.rename(columns={'Interaction Date':'Interaction_Date'}, inplace = True)
df['Interaction_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Interaction_Date'])
```

Is this efficient? I would use this approach on several large files and create a new raw data. I would then combine those files (standard column names and data types) and import that new raw data into a sqlite db and my Tableau Dashboards. I could also use .merge to tie several large files together (where Person_ID or Case_ID match).

Is it better to specify the column names and ACTUALLY modify them, or use an approach like:

```
header = 0 and names = [x, y , z]
```

Comment: Well, the answer for much of this is probably just going to be try and see what works best -- some of this seem to really be about database management rather than pandas.  Also, there are a lot of questions here, you are more likely to get some answers by breaking it into smaller pieces and asking more specific/detailed questions.

Comment: I just wonder if it is a good practice to physically rename and replace/select raw data and create new files from it. I do not want to start doing something which later down the road I will realize was a huge mistake.

Comment: Very generally speaking, I would never alter the original data.  Create new datasets or else make a copy of the original and then alter the copy.